# Applying text formula only if text is in the cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using 4 Excel sheets for collating text.

The formula I currently have in sheet 4 is:

```
=$Sheet1!A1&CHAR(10)&$Sheet2!A1&CHAR(10)&$Sheet3!A1&CHAR(10)
```

This allows me to write text in *Sheet 1 cell A1*, *Sheet 2 cell A1* and *Sheet 3 cell A1* which is then collated in *Sheet 4 cell A1* with a **Carriage Return**  after each line of text within their respective cell.

For example: if `hi` is in Sheet 1, `hello` in Sheet 2 and `there` is in sheet 3, then Sheet4 cell A1 would be:

```
hi
hello
there
```

However, if on Sheet2 there's nothing the text would be:

```
hi

there
```

It's keeping the Carriage Return corresponding to sheet 2, thus I want to do the same function but only if text is in the cell, getting:

```
hi
there
```

Not putting a Carriage Return for the text that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your formula to:

```
=$Sheet1!A1&IF($Sheet1!A1="","",CHAR(10))&$Sheet2!A1&IF($Sheet2!A1="","",CHAR(10))&$Sheet3!A1&IF($Sheet3!A1="","",CHAR(10))
```

The `IF` segments will check if there is an empty string to decide if it's neccesary to put CHAR(10) or not.